# Django multiple included forms with foreign key

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

i have a problem. Here is 2 related models:

```
class Auto(models.Model):
  ...
class Part(models.Model):
  ...
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Auto, blank = False, null = False)
```

So, i want to create next django form:

```
Auto1.field1  Auto1.Part1.field1 Auto1.field2
              Auto1.Part1.field2
              Auto1.Part2.field1
              Auto1.Part2.field2
              ...

Auto2.field1  Auto2.Part1.field1 Auto2.field2
              Auto2.Part1.field2
              Auto2.Part2.field1
              Auto2.Part2.field2
              ...
...
```

All fields must be updatable, as for model Auto and for model Part.
How can i do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to create both the `Part` and the `Auto` objects at the same time, in the same form? If so, you would need to hand code your forms in HTML, and your view would need to assemble the objects and create them in the right order.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to update both of this objects in the same form, not create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use [Inline formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). For example, assuming you have an Auto modelform it can be done like this:

```
autoforms = []
part_formsets = []
autos = Auto.objects.all()
PartFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Auto, Part, fields=('field1', 'field2'))
for auto in autos:
    autoform = AutoForm(instance=auto)
    autoforms.append(autoform)
    part_formset = PartFormSet(instance=auto)
    part_formsets.append(part_formset)
c = {'autoforms': autoforms, 'part_formsets': part_formsets}
return render(request, 'some.html', c)
```

Now you can iterate autoforms and part_formsets in template to get the desired forms. However, I have not checked if it is easy to render them in a template as you want.

Comment: Do you have any example of exactly my case?

Comment: I've tried to show some kind of how it can be done - have a look at the updated answer.